# array erroneously filled with the same value

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, output

Is this way of storing and/or printing/plotting data wrong? I should get two arrays filled with values that are different with respect to each other, but I keep obtaining the traceArray full of the same value repeated n times.

```
betaArray = []
WabArray = []
for j in range(n):
        A2 = getA(j)
        traceW = getW(K, A2, E)
        betaArray.append(j)
        traceArray.append(traceW)
        output_string = " {0} {1} \n".format(str(j), str(traceW))
        handle_2.write(output_string)
print betaArray
print WabArray
plt.plot(betaArray, WabArray, 'ro')
plt.show()
```

For completeness I include the definition of the function get W:

```
def getW(k, a, e):
    ktrans = k.transpose()
    w = k * a * ktrans * e
    valuew = w.trace()
    return valuew
```

Thanks to those who will help!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code snippet you've posted. However, are you expecting `w = k * a * ktrans * e` to be doing matrix multiplication?  (It's not, the `*` operator is element-wise.)